# Iterate over object and display it in table Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, angular6, ngfor

I have an object that looks like this:

```
obj = {'a': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'b': [1, 0, 0, 1], 'c': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'd': [1, 1, 1, 0]}
```

And I want to display it in a table like this:

```
No   | a | b | c | d 
0    | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1
1-3  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1
4-6  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1
7-9  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
      //a //b //c //d
```

How can I do this using `ngFor`?

Here is my html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">No</th>
    <th scope="col">a</th>
    <th scope="col">b</th>
    <th scope="col">c</th>
    <th scope="col">d</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1-3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4-6</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6-9</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

If i try to iterate over `obj`, I get

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

How can I solve this? Thank you for your time! [Here is a working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psgqdk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the keyvalue pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
 {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

(works for Angular 6.1+)

**EDIT:**

You can change your object to this:

```
obj = {'0': [0, 0, 1, 0], '1-3': [1, 0, 0, 1], '4-6': [0, 0, 0, 0], '6-9': [1, 1, 1, 0]}
```

and then in html:

```
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let x of obj | keyvalue">
    <td>{{x.key}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let data of x.value">{{data}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e3rfxt

Comment: I also tried that, but look what is happening: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psgqdk how can I solve this?

Comment: Actually, I've made a mistake, I didn't want to display the elements like that. Can you take a look on my question, I edited it.

Comment: the easiest way to do that would be to switch column names with row names: rename 'a' with '0',  rename 'b' with '1-3'  and so on